# How can I pass two queryset in same function using Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
def getProducts(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    p = Product.objects.all().filter(category = 1)
    serializer = ProductSerializer((products,p), many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)**
```

I want to pass p and products value in the serializer object. Can I do this here?

Comment: `product_qs = products | p` then do this: 
`serializer = ProductSerializer(product_qs, many=True)`

Comment: thanks man but can you please tell me what this operand do?? how it works

Answer (score 2):

with `|` you can union querysets. it merges two querysets together.

so you can do it:

```
union_products = products | p  
serializer = ProductSerializer(union_products, many=True)
```

***Note:*** this doesn't work on querysets from two different models.